# Print all the paths of the Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on a problem to print all the paths of the binary tree and this gives result. I create a global variable ***sw*** and also in the recursion of the ***printAllRootToLeafPaths*** method, a String variable ***path*** is being used. Is there some way I can make ***sw*** and ***path*** only inside the ***printAllRootToLeafPaths*** method ? So, the method will be like the following.

```
public static ArrayList<String> printAllRootToLeafPaths(TreeNode node ){

   /*
      String path and ArrayList<String> sw will be initiated here 
   */
}

==============================================================================

import java.io.*;
import  java.util.*; 

class TreeNode {

      int val;
      TreeNode left;
      TreeNode right;

      TreeNode(int x) { 
        val = x; 
    }
}


public class myTest {



    public static ArrayList<String> sw = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    public static void main ( String[] args ){

        TreeNode root = new TreeNode( 1 );

        root.left= new TreeNode( 2 ) ;
        root.left.left =  new TreeNode( 5 );

        root.right =  new TreeNode(3);


        sw =  printAllRootToLeafPaths( root, new String() ); 
        String[] result =  new String[ sw.size() ]; 
        int count =  0 ; 

        for ( String s: sw ){

            result[count] = '"'+ s + '"'; 
            count++; 
        }

        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( result ) );

    }


    public static ArrayList<String> printAllRootToLeafPaths(TreeNode node, String path ) {

        if( node==null ) return null ; 

        path += String.valueOf(node.val)+ "->"; 

        if( node.left == null && node.right == null ){

            String my = path.substring(0, path.length() -2 ); 
            sw.add( my );

            // optional 
            path = ""; 
        }

        else {

            printAllRootToLeafPaths( node.left, new String (path) );
            printAllRootToLeafPaths( node.right, new String (path)  );
        }  

        return sw ;     
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sw =   printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.left, new String());
sw =   printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.right, new String());
```

when you pass the path (instead of `new String()` is that you use a single object in all methods call, which means that, when you return to the original caller, the object is not in the same state as it was.Then Call the recursive methods

Comment: Perhaps, I don't understand the answer properly.  I would like to use printAllRootToLeafPaths method with only one argument -> printAllRootToLeafPaths( TreeNode node ). Besides, where do I  need to initiate sw and path ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this solution:

```
class TreeNode {

    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
}
public class myTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);

        root.left = new TreeNode(2);
        root.left.left = new TreeNode(5);

        root.right = new TreeNode(3);

        printAllRootToLeafPaths(root, new String());

    }

    public static void printAllRootToLeafPaths(TreeNode node, String path) {
        path = path + " -> " + node.val;
        if (isLeaf(node)) {

            System.out.println(path);
        } else if (node.left == null && node.right != null) {
            printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.right, path);
        } else if (node.left != null && node.right == null) {
            printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.left, path);
        } else {
            printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.left, path);
            printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.right, path);
        }

    }

    public static boolean isLeaf(TreeNode t) {
        if (t.left == null && t.right == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

As you can see, you only need the **path** string inside printAllRootToLeafPaths. However, this function got two parameters. You can replace the second parameter for a global variable, but with recursion it is harder to maintain.

The result of this code is:

```
-> 1 -> 2 -> 5
-> 1 -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static List<String> printAllRootToLeafPaths(TreeNode node ){

       /*
          String path and ArrayList<String> sw will be initiated here 
       */
     List<String> sw =new ArrayList<String>();
     StringBuilder path=new StringBuilder();
     printAllRootToLeafPaths(TreeNode node,path,sw ) ;
    }
```

Below function needs to pass the reference to the list in each call if it is not static

```
   public static List<String> printAllRootToLeafPaths(TreeNode node, StringBuilder path,List<String> pathList ) 
    {
     ...
    else {
           printAllRootToLeafPaths( node.left, new StringBuilder (path.toString()),pathList );
           printAllRootToLeafPaths( node.right, new StringBuilder (path.toString()),pathList  );
            }
```